# Disabled textfield when dropdownbutton item was choose

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
how to disable textfield if one of dropdownbutton value is selected in flutter
```

`

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownSelected {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropDownItem = [
      const DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "LION",
          child: Text(
            "Lion Insurance",
          )),
      const DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "General",
          child: Text(
            "General Insurance",
            
          )),
    ];
    return dropDownItem;
  }
```

i want to make dropdownbutton and textfield, i just want if "General Insurance" has choose than the textfield will disabled and and will be filled with "-" value. but if the user chooses "Lion Insurance" then the textfield can be filled by the user.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Textfield has an enabled parameter, so you can just check when your current value from your DropDownMenu is selected with a value and then pass your textfield to enable false

Comment: can you give me an example sir? i'm sorry i just a beginner in flutter

Comment: provide all your class code so we can help u more

Comment: Maybe to progress in your language skills you should look for topics - tutorials. Here a tutorial similar to your problem -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoT7l0C8MS4

Answer (score 1):

The example below should help you to solve your problem.

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  String? dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            enabled: dropdownValue == null,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
              if (newValue != null) {
                controller.text = '-';
              }
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```